# MongoDB - aggregation - Update after lookup and match

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a model **Product** and a model **Event**. Each product has an **Event** associated, and each **Event** has a date. Also each product has a virtual property called **availability**

I need to set **availability** to false, when the input date matches the date in Event.

So far I have filter all the products that matches the given date like this:

```
exports.checkDateAvailability = function (req, res) {
  const dateAvailability = moment(req.query.dateAvailability).format("DD-MM-YYYY")

  Product.aggregate([
    {
      $lookup: { from: Event.collection.name, localField: 'event', foreignField: '_id', as: 'event' }
    },
    {
      $unwind: '$event',
    },
    {
      $addFields: { date: { $dateToString: { date: '$event.date', format: "%d-%m-%Y" } } }
    },
    {
      $match: { date: dateAvailability },
    },

  ]).then(response => { res.send(response) })
}
```

Now I want to update those products availability property to false. I know that from version 4.2 it is available the [update command](https://docs.mongodb.com/master/reference/command/update/index.html#update-command-example-agg), but I failed implementing it after the $match.
Any idea on how can I proceed?

Comment: I don't think you'll be able to read this, manipulate & write it back in one query, cause from 4.2 you can use `$merge` to write aggregation result but that too merging results in another collection but not on same, you can use `$out` `>3.2` that also creates a whole new collection if passed in name doesn't match with name existing collection name else will overwrite existing..Maybe you can use all those records using `bulkWrite` do you want me to give a query ? or you can check documentation & do it..

Comment: Yes that would be very helpful...do you think that's the best option to do this?.

Comment: yes, I guess that’s the only option